# Please remove sobot from the IRC channel

Tags: feature-request

It's annoying
It's useless
If I wanted to see questions I would go to SO site

Comment: What does *sobot* mean? Is it even an acronym? Also, is it *sobot*, *SObot*, or *SOBOT*, some other capitalisation variation, or all of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore sobot using the command "/ignore sobot"

Alternatively, you can voice your concerns with the maker of the bot, zigdon, who frequents the same channel.

Comment: But the freenode web client doesn't accept this command

Answer (score 3):

From my experience in the IRC, if you remove SObot, you remove the only person actually communicating :)

Comment: I've felt for a long time that sobot is the reason why nobody really communicates. That's why I ignore it.

Comment: @TheTXI Could be. So that would mean it would have to be silenced globally, rather than locally - right?

Comment: I think if enough person ignored it (and I know a lot of people do already), you could potentially see more conversation in there. I don't have a problem with it being in there for people who may like it. That's why we all have our own ability to ignore.

Comment: IIRC from my IRC days.. (many many years ago) you can post messages to all entering users. It could say "To ignore SObot, type /ignore SObot" That way no one has to wonder.

Comment: @devinb But the freenode web client doesn't accept this command

Answer (score 3):

I just use my IRC software to ignore sobot. That way those that like the new question feed can have it, but I don't have to watch it update every 2 minutes.

As a side note, no matter what the IRC channel might say about itself it's absolutely NOT official and the StackOverflow team has NO control over it. So you'd really be better off requesting this there.